# Failing Parse background job when using beforesave with thousands of objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code, before-save

I am using a background job to query a json with thousands of objects to initially populate my database. I have also implemented the beforesave function to prevent any duplicate entries. However, once I implemented this, it seems my background job called response.error and does not save all objects. It looks like I might be exceeding the requests/sec? I would really appreciate if someone could take a look at my code and tell me why it is not saving all entries successfully.

Here is my background job:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("testing", function(request, response) {

    var json;

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: stringURL + pageNumber.toString(),
        success: function(httpResponse) {

        json = httpResponse.data;
        console.log("total is: " + json["meta"].total);
        console.log("object 1 is: " + json["events"][1].title);
        return json;
        }
    //after getting the json, save all 1000
    }).then(function() {
 //helper function called
        saveObjects(json).then(function() {
            response.success("success");
        },
        function(error) {
            response.error("nooooo");
        });
  });
});

function saveObjects(json) {
    var promises = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var newEvent = new Event();
        promises.push(newEvent.save(new Event(json["events"][i])));
    }
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}
```

Here is my beforesave code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Event", function(request, response) {
    var newEvent = request.object;
    var Event = Parse.Object.extend("Event");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Event");

    query.equalTo("title", newEvent.get("title"));
    query.equalTo("datetime_utc", newEvent.get("datetime_utc"));
    query.equalTo("url", newEvent.get("url"));
    query.first({

    success: function(temp) {
        response.error({errorCode:123,errorMsg:"Event already exist!"});          
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.success();
    }
    });
});
```

Thanks I really appreciate any help... I've been stuck for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a request rate issue, then you could probably use something like [node-function-rate-limit](https://github.com/wankdanker/node-function-rate-limit) but it's fairly simple to write your own rate limiting batcher. See `doInBatches()` below.

Also, when using promise-returning methods that also offer a "success:..." callback, it's better not to mix the two styles. It may behave as expected but you are denied the opportunity to pass results from the "success:..." callback to the rest of the promise chain. As you can see below, the "success:..." code has simply been shuffled into the `.then()` callback.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("testing", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: stringURL + pageNumber.toString()
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        var json = httpResponse.data;
        // console.log("total is: " + json.meta.total);
        // console.log("object 1 is: " + json.events[1].title);
        /* helper function called */
        doInBatches(json.events, 30, 1000, function(evt, i) {
                var newEvent = new Event();
            return newEvent.save(new Event(evt));
        }).then(function() {
            response.success('success');
        }, function(error) {
            response.error('nooooo');
        });
    });
});

// Async batcher.
function doInBatches(arr, batchSize, delay, fn) {
    function delayAsync() {
        var p = new Parse.Promise();
        setTimeout(p.resolve, delay);
        return p;
    }
    function saveBatch(start) {
        if(start < arr.length) {
            return Parse.Promise.when(arr.slice(start, start+batchSize).map(fn))
            .then(delayAsync) // delay between batches
            .then(function() {
                return saveBatch(start + batchSize);
            });
        } else {
            return Parse.Promise.as();
        }
    }
    return saveBatch(0);
}
```

I can't see how or why the beforesave code might affect things.